# How do I create a function that adds multiple arrays in C++

Tags: arrays, function

So Im trying to create a function that adds the values of another set of arrays. Im using a function that stores one digit per array and then adds them. In my main body im storing these number in a set of arrays as well but when I try to apply this function to an array i get this error D:\Documents\C++\bar_code\other.cpp|45|error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

this is the function:

```
int addition(int numbers[])
{


int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<=4; i++)
{
    sum = sum + numbers[i];

}
return sum;
}
```

and here im calling it

```
    sumatoria = addition(nums[i]);

    cout << sumatoria << endl;
```

Comment: `nums[i]` is an `int`; `numbers` parameter is `int*`. Use `addition(nums)` instead of `addition(nums[i])`.

Comment: Hey, try removing the `i` form `sumatoria = addition(nums[i]);
`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing as array with index that would pass only one value and you are trying to get as array. You must pass the value as addition(nums) in which the pointer where the array is stored will be passed and you will get expected result